# how to execute a command after resume from suspend?

Tags: scripts, suspend-resume, session

I've got a script that is executed in order to have suspending/resuming working in my laptop. Then I have another series of `xinput`,`xkbset` and `xmodmap` commands that are executed when I initiate a session to have two-finger scrolling and keyboard shortcuts set up. When I resume from suspend, two-finger scrolling and my keyboard shortcuts won't work. I need to manually execute the commands in the second file again. How can I add those to the suspend/resume script to have this done automatically? See below:

### suspend/resume script

/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd

```
#!/bin/sh
#inspired by http://art.ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9744970&postcount=19
#...and http://thecodecentral.com/2011/01/18/fix-ubuntu-10-10-suspendhibernate-not-working-bug    
# tidied by tqzzaa :)

VERSION=1.1
DEV_LIST=/tmp/usb-dev-list
DRIVERS_DIR=/sys/bus/pci/drivers
DRIVERS="ehci xhci" # ehci_hcd, xhci_hcd
HEX="[[:xdigit:]]"
MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS=2
BIND_WAIT=0.1

unbindDev() {
  echo -n > $DEV_LIST 2>/dev/null
  for driver in $DRIVERS; do
    DDIR=$DRIVERS_DIR/${driver}_hcd
    for dev in `ls $DDIR 2>/dev/null | egrep "^$HEX+:$HEX+:$HEX"`; do
      echo -n "$dev" > $DDIR/unbind
      echo "$driver $dev" >> $DEV_LIST
    done
  done
}

bindDev() {
  if [ -s $DEV_LIST ]; then
    while read driver dev; do
      DDIR=$DRIVERS_DIR/${driver}_hcd
      while [ $((MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS)) -gt 0 ]; do
          echo -n "$dev" > $DDIR/bind
          if [ ! -L "$DDIR/$dev" ]; then
            sleep $BIND_WAIT
          else
            break
          fi
          MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS=$((MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS-1))
      done  
    done < $DEV_LIST
  fi
  rm $DEV_LIST 2>/dev/null
}

case "$1" in
  hibernate|suspend) unbindDev;;
  resume|thaw)       bindDev;;
esac
```

### touchpad two-finger scrolling and keyboard shortcuts script

```
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Two-Finger Scrolling" 8 1
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 8 1 1
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure" 32 10
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Width" 32 8
setxkbmap -layout gb
xkbset m
xkbset exp =m
xmodmap -e "keycode 135 = Pointer_Button2"
```

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/226278/run-script-on-wakeup/483714. See also my comment at http://askubuntu.com/a/483714/170127.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can place your scripts in the `/etc/pm/sleep.d` directory to have them run after suspend.  You will need to add a conditional to make your script run only during resume and not during the suspend process as well.  For example, your touchpad script would look like:

```
case "${1}" in
    resume|thaw)
        DISPLAY=:0.0 ; export DISPLAY
        xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Two-Finger Scrolling" 8 1
        xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 8 1 1
        xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure" 32 10
        xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Width" 32 8
        setxkbmap -layout gb
        xkbset m
        xkbset exp =m
        su $USER -c "sleep 3; /usr/bin/xmodmap -e "keycode 135 = Pointer_Button2"" &
;;
esac
```

Be sure your script is marked globally executable and change $USER to the corresponding username.

You can find more detailed information in the pm-suspend manpage (`man pm-suspend`) or by looking at the documentation in `/usr/share/doc/pm-utils` (particularly `/usr/share/doc/pm-utils/HOWTO.hooks.gz`).

Comment: How do I need to call this script if the suspend/resume is called `20_something`?

Comment: It can be called whatever you like.  It's a good idea to start it with a number between 00-49, per the pm-suspend manpage: "00 - 49   User and most package supplied hooks. If a hook assumes that all of the usual services and userspace infrastructure is still running, it should be here."

Comment: [Another (now deleted) answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/645901/178596) had this: 'please note the following bug report: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pm-utils/+bug/1455097 after upgrading to vivid scripts need to be put into `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`'

Comment: On **Ubuntu 15.10**, the script has to be in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` instead of  `/etc/pm/sleep`.

Comment: On **Ubuntu 16.04** the arguments given to the script are `pre` before entering suspend and `post` after resume instead of `suspend` and `resume`

Comment: Tried the last two comments here on yakkety (16.10), and it didn't work.  How to troubleshoot?

Comment: Didn't worked any of the locations in 16.04... any workaround or sugestion?

Comment: 16.04 uses systemd. This answer is outdated for systemd systems. See the other answer here.

Comment: thanks for showing the DISPLAY setting; xinput scripts need this.

Answer (score 13):

On Ubuntu 16.04 I had to create service this way:

1. create file

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/systemd/system/somename.service
   ```
2. put inside

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Some description
   Before=sleep.target
   StopWhenUnneeded=yes

   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   RemainAfterExit=yes
   ExecStop=-/path/to/your/script.sh

   [Install]
   WantedBy=sleep.target
   ```
3. enable service

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable somename
   ```
4. (optional) if not working after resume from suspend > check for errors with

   ```
   journalctl -u somename.service
   ```

Comment: This also seems to work on Ubuntu 18.04, thanks!

Comment: Why does Ubuntu leave /etc/pm/sleep.d lying around if it doesn't use it?  It is confusing and misleading.

Comment: This worked for me on ubuntu 18.04 (actually KDE Neon), but I had to
a): Under [Service], put User=tim so that script runs as my user
b) in my script, do DISPLAY=:0.0 ; export DISPLAY

Answer (score 11):

Open this file:

```
sudo vim /lib/systemd/system-sleep/hdparm
```

Contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in 
  post)
    /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/95hdparm-apm resume
    ## Paste your command to run your script
    ;; esac
```

Your command will execute with **admin privileges**.

Comment: This worked with kubuntu 18.04.  Using another file other than hdparm in the same directory didn't work.

Comment: it does not work on Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Works on Debian 10

Comment: @Phil, maybe you did not give another file in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` executable permission. Answer on duplicate Q here gives lots of details on systemd way: https://askubuntu.com/a/620328/1152748

Comment: This fails for X commands on Ubuntu because the root user doesn't have access to the display of the logged in user. The answer from janot worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the version I use to restart my VPN daemon after resume:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
        pre)
                echo "$(date) - $1: Restarting norvpnd" >> /tmp/nordvpn/suspend.txt
                /usr/bin/systemctl restart nordvpnd
                ;;
        post)
                echo "$(date)-  $1: Doing nothing" >> /tmp/nordvpn/suspend.txt
                ;;
esac
```

This file is put in:

```
/lib/systemd/system-sleep//00restart_nordvpnd.sh
```

This works fine in  Ubuntu 20.4. The `pre` part is executed before putting the computer to sleep (`suspend`) and the `post` part is executed when it is resumed, as that can be verified by looking at the `/tmp/nordvpn/suspend.txt` file.

Side note (irrelevant to the subject but worth noting): Regarding the task in this example, it might seem illogical to restart a daemon before putting the computer to sleep, but it's the (only?) way it works.

Comment: This gives me "Failed to execute /lib/systemd/system-sleep/00_pre-and-post-suspend.sh: Not a directory" when I check with 'journalctl -u systemd-suspend.service' (in 20.04) - any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: @Stefan, do you have that entry in your file system, is it directory? check with `ls -l  /lib/systemd/system-sleep/00_pre-and-post-suspend.sh`.