# Laptop: Internal LCD does not get reactivated

Tags: multiple-monitors, laptop, thinkpad, external-monitor, 13.10

Hi i have a ThinkPad T430 with an external monitor plugged into docking-station via VGA.

When i close the lid and reopen it, my internal display stays black and does not get reactivated.

I'm using a fresh install of an Ubuntu Saucy daily build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same problem with my Thinkpad T430. I have upgrade from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10.

I have solved this problem using these commands. You need to explicit set mode with `--mode` option, without `--mode` it won't work:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1600x900
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1600x900 --left-of VGA1
```

NOTE: you should change 1600x900 to **your** screen resolution, to get a list of supported resolutions enter this command:

```
xrandr
```

Looks like the wake up / resume script does not explicitly set this after resume from suspend.

**Simple automatic solution**: create a new file named: /etc/pm/sleep.d/01_thinkpadlcd with below script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#copy to /etc/pm/sleep.d
LOGFILE="/var/log/sleep.log"

case "$1" in
        resume|thaw)
                echo "Resumed from suspend at `date`" >> "$LOGFILE"
                xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1600x900 --left-of VGA1
                echo "Thinkpad built-in monitor turned on"
                ;;
esac
```

Remember to set execution bit for it:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/01_thinkpadlcd
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be neat if there was a script to be executed at [wake-up](http://askubuntu.com/questions/226278/run-script-on-wakeup)... (just hinting at it, because I don't have the time to write it myself :P)

Comment: @MadMike I add a resume script as requested ;)

Comment: i opend also a bugreport @ launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1239813 can you click, that this also affects you? Thanks anyway!