# Ubuntu 14.04 Intel Brightness After Resume

Tags: 14.04, suspend, brightness

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Dell Inspiron laptop.

Seeing that my hotkeys didn't work, I followed the instructions [here](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/) and everything was going smooth.

Except for when I close the lid to my laptop. When I do that, it goes into suspend and when I reopen it, the screen has zero backlight making it virtually impossible to see. Is there any way to fix the resume-issue?

Sure, I could just use the newly-fixed hotkeys, but it's kind of annoying to do every time...

Thanks for any advice you could give me.

Comment: Try to add a script, like in http://askubuntu.com/questions/226278/run-script-on-wakeup

Comment: Nothing really happens when I run a script like that. The screen brightens up, then blacks out and reloads on the login screen but the screen is still dark.

Comment: Are you sure it has something to do with your hotkey fix? I have the same problem without these fixes and I think it is described in this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1298578. Unfortunately, nothing seems to happen there...