# Wifi won't connect after suspend Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I have an Thinkpad R61e that I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on. When the system suspends WiFi will not connect until I reboot. I've tried restarting network manager, but this does not correct the problem.  Any suggestions or help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `service networking restart` set up using this method: http://askubuntu.com/questions/226278/run-script-on-wakeup

Comment: You can try restarting  network manager `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`

Comment: I tried restarting network-manager.service but this did not correct the problem. One thing I notice when I go into network setting gui is that only my network shows up and it shows as out of range. Usually there are 14 or 15 that show.  This issue occurs randomly and only when coming out of standby.  Thanks