# why does my script not run on wakeup

Tags: wireless, scripts, suspend

I've followed istructions found on [Run Script on Wakeup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226278/run-script-on-wakeup) to do the following:
I have a ASUS Zenbook and since I upgraded to `16.04`, the wifi stays disconnected on resume. I wrote a script that I can execute manually after wakeup (and entering the root pewd) and it properly hooks my wifi adapter up to my network. The script looks like:

```
$ cat wifi-resume.sh 
systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

so, following the instructions I created a script in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/` called `96wifi-resume` which looks like:

```
# cat 96wifi-resume 
#!/bin/sh
# On my ASUS Zenbook, this script is used to restart the wifi on resume.
# Date 11/04/2016 Ron Eggler

[ -f /bin/systemctl ] || exit $NA

case "$1" in
        hibernate|suspend)
                exit $NA
                ;;
        thaw|resume) 
                systemctl restart network-manager.service
                ;;
        *) exit $NA
                ;;
esac
```

permissions are set to `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root` but it still does not seem to work, why not, what am I doing wrong here?

**edit 1**

However, I have replaced all the `exit $NA`s with `exit 0` and it still doesn't seem to work correctly, however, when I call `:/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d# ./96wifi-resume resume` from the shell, it seems to work as expected

Comment: What does `$NA` expand to?

Comment: ledI was wondering the same but don't actually know, that's what I copied from `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led` as recommended on http://askubuntu.com/questions/226278/run-script-on-wakeup . `echo $NA` doesn't give me nothing. It shouldn't hurt though, would it?

Comment: Please see **edit 1** above