# Wakeup script doesn't work

Tags: 18.04, bash, suspend

I have a script that remaps my keyboard. It executes as it should on login but doesn't work on resume. The command is `xmodmap .Xmodmap` or with full path: `/usr/bin/xmodmap /home/arash/.Xmodmap`.

I've used Ubuntu's startup application process and for resume, I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226278/run-script-on-wakeup) by adding a bash script to `/lib/systemd/system-sleep`:

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "Going to $2..."
    exit 0
    ;;
  post/*)
    echo "Waking up from $2..."
    /usr/bin/xmodmap /home/arash/.Xmodmap
    ;;
esac
```

and have made it executable with `sudo chmod x+a`.

For some reason it doens't work and I can just see the following message in the logs:

> /lib/systemd/system-sleep/key_corrector.sh failed with exit status 1.

By searching a bit, I encountered a few similar cases, (like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775934/script-not-running-on-resume-wakeup-in-ubuntu) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845679/why-does-my-script-not-run-on-wakeup)), but none of them provide any help. I'm open to any idea that solves this once for all!

**Further info**:

- I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.
- It used to work for some time. I believe after an `autoremove`, it broke.
- I'm almost a noob and appreciate more the most simple answers.
  Is there any bug in the bash script or the location

---

**UPDATE**:

A combination of all the methods out there worked out for me **as long as I do not reboot**. Still, I'm not sure why it didn't and why it does now. Just for the record, however, this is what I did:

Based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1041358/798242), I made a services `key_corrector.service` that contains the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Corrects the key hopefully...
After=sleep.target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=arash
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStop=/home/arash/k.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

and activate it by

```
sudo systemctl enable key_corrector
```

note that I had to add `User` to the service as indicated in the last comment of that answer. Also, as stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/620328/798242) one has to make the script (in my case `k.sh`) executable by:

```
sudo chmod +x /home/arash/k.sh
```

finally, in `k.sh` itself, I had to set the `DISPLAY` to zero. The full contamination of this bash file is:

```
#!/bin/sh
DISPLAY=:0.0 ; export DISPLAY
/usr/bin/xmodmap /home/arash/.Xmodmap
```

Referring to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/483714/798242) answer as well, I have used the absolute path of each command.

Comment: It seems weird to modify `/lib` files, nowadays those kind of things normally go in `/etc` (see `man 7 file-hierarchy`) according to my experience on Linux. I would definitely try this answer <https://askubuntu.com/a/1041358>. The procedure described in it is very familiar to me. Hope it helps!

Comment: Related: [How to disable multimedia keys entirely? 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200893/how-to-disable-multimedia-keys-entirely-18-04-lts)