# Battery status is slow to update

Tags: 16.04, laptop, battery

I have a 2008 MacBook Air (model A1237) with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed on it.

I managed to solve some other problems, but I can't figure out how to find a solution to this one...

Basically the battery status does not update very quickly... This leads to shut downs of the computer when the shown battery percentage is still 50%...

Another thing that happens is that, when plugging in the power cord, it takes about 2 minutes to update, even though the laptop is charging. This means that when I'm working on stuff and the computer is running out of battery I can't tell that it's happening and the computer shuts down or goes to stand-by without warning.

Any solutions? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: How old is that battery? If as old as the MacBook then the time to replace it was some 4 years ago...

Comment: I bought it last year, so it's pretty new... The point is that it works flawlessly while on OSX

Comment: I have a MacBook 6.1 of almost the same age (late 2009) - and battery meter at 16.04 also behaves weird here: it never shows anything between 70% and 100%. It first started with original battery (at the same time MacOS started reporting it as dying), so I've replaced it with a new one, but from AliExpress. But nothing changed. So it might be some problem with old MacBooks vs Ubuntu battery metering. Or ot might be just dead batteries :)

Comment: Possible thread necromancy here, but I've got the same issue on a laptop that shipped with Windows. One such example had shown the percentage as still sitting at 15%, but the battery was really at 5% and the laptop's hardware-based low-power mode had already activated. I believe this is due to some sort of change (or possible bug?) related to Ubuntu, as when the laptop still ran Windows the battery meter was always accurate.

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem as well. This is not a solution but workarounds that work for me I have found:

`acpi` shows the correct battery state and charging status.

`sudo service upower restart` forces the battery status of upower to update. I would like this to happen every time I resume my computer from hibernation so after I charge my laptop I can actually see the progress. I've come up with the following script [that runs on wake](https://askubuntu.com/a/620328/477026):

```
# Restart upower on wake (put in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/)
#!/bin/sh
case $1
  post)
    service upower restart ;;
esac
```

I would love a real solution to this problem. I'll update my answer if I can find one.

Comment: I would avoid using sleep hooks for executing scripts as the hooks causes the remaining systemd services that _properly_ execute on wakeup to hang until the sleep script executes. It's preferred to use a new systemd service with `Before=sleep.target` or `After=sleep.target`  in your `Unit`.

Comment: @blockloop here's a solution that doesn't run on wake https://askubuntu.com/a/878579/477026