# Internet not working after switching wifi

Tags: network-manager, internet, xps

I recently reinstalled my laptop with ubuntu gnome 16.10. I previously had 16.04 which was upgraded from 15.10, but this time I installed clean. My wifi-module works fine and I connect to networks successfully. On the first network, the internet is fine, but when I go to work for example (and thus switch wifi-network) I have to restart the network-manager for the internet to work. It will connect to the wifi-network, but the internet won't work.

Laptop: Dell XPS 13, 9350

EDIT 1: it doesn't (only?) happen after switching wifi, it happens everytime I suspend the laptop and unsuspend it (i.e. close the lid and open it again).

Comment: Check that your Network adapter has low power mode "enabled", this use to happen to me on a windows 8.1/10 machine when machine went into sleep or hibernate mode.

Answer (score 2):

Create a script that restarts your NetworkManager after suspend:

```
sudo gedit /etc/systemd/system/wifi-resume.service
```

Paste the following in it:

```
#/etc/systemd/system/wifi-resume.service
#sudo systemctl enable wifi-resume.service
[Unit]
Description=Restart networkmanager at resume
After=suspend.target
After=hibernate.target
After=hybrid-sleep.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart network-manager.service

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
WantedBy=hibernate.target
WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
```

Now activate it:

```
sudo systemctl enable wifi-resume.service
```

From [Wifi doesn't work after suspend after 16.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade) but can't mark as dupe, credits to [Joakim Koed](https://askubuntu.com/users/464631/joakim-koed).

Comment: It's not really a fix to the problem, more a hack around it, right?

Comment: @RienHeuver In the basest sense yes, it is a fix, but it also is a hack. Try it and see if it works for your needs. There aren't any concrete fixes, as this is a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1574347

Comment: Well, it sort of fixes the problem. Thing is though, that my network-icon is no longer showing in my upper-right corner (Gnome). It's not a huge problem, but it's a nice thing to have when I want to switch networks quickly. (I know, I can access network-settings in other ways, but this is an issue to the fix either way.)

Comment: @RienHeuver What happens if you create a script that restarts the gnome-panel at wakeup? Follow the instructions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/226278/run-script-on-wakeup) and instead of the example body add `killall gnome-panel` (make sure to end the script with `esac`!).

Comment: Does the network-icon really not work? I find that on my laptop, it disappears but will reappear if I click and hover around where it should be.

Comment: For some reason the network-icon started working again after the next resume.  So it works now (except for it being a hacky fix).

Answer (score 0):

Check for ubuntu 'network manager' set as "No Proxy" and open terminal

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

Or you can do

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```