# How to run script after resuming from sleep?

Tags: startup-applications

I have a custom script (uses $DISPLAY) for setting up the extra buttons on my mouse. I want to run this script every time I log into the system. I have added the script as a Startup Application via the Ubuntu (18.10) GUI (Gnome 3.30.1). It runs after I turn on my PC or reboot it, but fails to run after the PC resumes from sleep.

How can I make the script run after the PC resumes from sleep? (Preferably without having to maintain a separate script).

Comment: Read `man pm-action` to see how to add a script to Suspend/Resume/Sleep/Wake. You'll have to hard-code the value of `$DISPLAY`, and consider `xhost +localhost` to give the script access to your X windows

Comment: Is pm-suspend different from the suspend option in Gnome3 or is it the same thing? After resuming from a pm-suspend I don't get a login screen but after resuming from a normal sleep I do see the login screen.

Comment: Ok it looks like my system uses `systemctl suspend` to goto sleep. How can I configure it to run a custom script after I login?

Comment: Placing a script in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/ does work but now its unable to access the DISPLAY variable. Exporting it as :0 don't help either.

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/226278/run-script-on-wakeup & https://askubuntu.com/questions/92218/how-to-execute-a-command-after-resume-from-suspend.

Answer (score 6):

## Run Script when Resuming from Suspend

Create a new file `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/resume` and copy in:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "Going to $2..."
    # Place your pre suspend commands here, or `exit 0`
    # if no pre suspend action required
    exit 0
    ;;
  post/*)
    echo "Waking up from $2..."
    # Place your post suspend (resume) commands here, or `exit 0` 
    # if no post suspend action required
    mouse_script.sh
    ;;
esac
```

**NOTE:** replace user `mouse_script.sh` (third line from the bottom) with your script name. Provide the full path name if the script is not in your path (`echo $PATH`).

Then mark it executable with the command:

```
sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/resume
```

Comment: Not working for Ubuntu Budgie 19.04.

Comment: Can you insert your custom script into your question so I can test?

Comment: This script in the given place works for me with Ubuntu 18.04. Redirect the echo output to e. g. `/root/systemd-sleep.log` to debug it.

Answer (score -1):

You can call it from /etc/init.d/rc.local

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/rc.local
```

and add the path to your script

Comment: Does not work. Any other ideas?