# Use pm-suspend instead of suspend on lid close

Tags: suspend, power-management, laptop, systemd, lid

From testing on my Ubuntu 20.04 Thinkpad P51 laptop (Quadro M1200 running proprietary driver 510.39.01), `systemctl suspend` will only suspend for a few seconds then wake again, while `sudo pm-suspend` appears to work correctly.

From `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, all commands are commented but I assume the "HandleLidSwitch=suspend" command would be the one from systemctl. Can I configure it to use `pm-suspend`?

Comment: have you tried the latest update , might fix your original problem. 5.13.0-27 generic kernel

Comment: I have not. is there a specific reason this issue may be fixed?

Comment: nothing specific except there was some progress in suspending for me. I checked that processes had suspended, though I had to ctrl-left click mouse (another thread here on that) to resume and now I discover that a 6hr battery life left under this 'suspend' does not go more than 6 hours, so it probably is not properly suspending anyway. the other machine, also a Ryzen, has no issues. some are saying here 5.15xx is the fix.  I do a CLonezilla partition backup before any updates. might be worth a try.

Comment: a suggestion you could link in a script to lid suspend event, maybe, to unsuspend, or wait a couple of seconds, and then run your one. https://askubuntu.com/questions/226278/run-script-on-wakeup#620328