# No wlan after standby

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10, suspend

since I use Ubuntu 13.10, I'm experiencing a bug:

1. I activate standby
2. I press any key to continue working on my laptop
3. The computer is on again, but the wlan doesn't work.

[image: After Standby…]
[image: Hitting "Enable network"]

→ The wlan network then is disabled by default, but I can't enable it, it doesn't shows any network available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a problem of the driver or of network manager. In the latter case, try to see if

```
% sudo restart network-manager
```

works. If it works, you can add the network-manager restart at resume: there are a lot of hints and suggestions here: [how to execute a command after resume from suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92218/how-to-execute-a-command-after-resume-from-suspend)

Otherwise, you should try to load/unload the wireless driver --- you can find it with

```
% nm-tool | grep Driver
Driver: atl1c
Driver: ath9k
```

(you will have the list of drivers, one of them is you wireless one), and try to unload and reload it:

```
sudo rmmod ath9k
sudo modprobe ath9k
```

If this second option does work, you can add the modules to the list of modules to be loaded/unloaded at suspend/resume,

```
% sudo sudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config
```

And adding

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="ath9k"
```

there. (**Disclaimer**: it worked for me in 12.04. Never tried with newer Ubuntu).