# Is there any way to be notified about system events in Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, indicator, date, events

I want to write an application indicator for Unity to show a single number and a tooltip. I want to update this number when the date changes i.e. on 24:00 and I need to update it if computer wakes up from hibernate or standby.

Is there any way to be notified about above mentioned events in Ubuntu? I look for any API for watching and monitoring date/time changes and signals in the system. I want to avoid scanning system time to catch the changes.

Answer (score 0):

when the date changes -- use cron (man at); also [how to execute a command after resume from suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92218/how-to-execute-a-command-after-resume-from-suspend)

Another thing is for app to be notified. Usual thing for IPC is signal handler (POSIX setsig()) and using kill command with custom signal id, e.g. SIGUSR1. Do you write with C?

Comment: I write the app indicator using python. I knew about cron but I wanted to avoid it and to see if there is anything like a publisher/subscriber pattern possible in Ubuntu desktop. Moreover I want everything work out of the box, I mean no further steps after installing the app indicator.