# Touchpad stopped working after suspending system

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, suspend, touchpad

I use Ubuntu 16.04, and if I suspend the system, the touchpad stops working and requires a reboot before working again.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix/prevent it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Touchpad not working after suspending laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671910/touchpad-not-working-after-suspending-laptop)

Comment: In general, correctly suspending a system needs good hardware support.  Can you tell us something about your computer?

Comment: @OttToomet Notebook PC, Asus X452L,64-bit

Comment: Do you know which chipset?  Which touchpad model?  Which kernel?  I have little idea but these are the data you can start googling about.  Have you searched for other users with a similar laptop?

Comment: @OttToomet kernel: 4.4.0-31-generic, touchpad: synaptics,

Comment: Just a generic suggestion--try to install a newer kernel.  I think 4.11 exists for xenial, and you can also compile the most recent one.