# Keyboard works fine, but no mouse after computer wakes up from sleep

Tags: 18.04, mouse

first time Ubuntu user here. ubuntu 18.04. Sorry if this has been asked before. I have a wireless Fenifox mouse keyboard both using the same usb wireless dongle. They worked right out of the box without any drivers. I have my screen set to go to sleep after 15 minutes. When I wake the computer back up, the keyboard works fine, but the mouse does not work. I have to toggle the little power on /off under the mouse a few times and move the mouse around a bunch before the cursor starts working again. This is never a problem when first turning on the computer, just when it wakes back up from sleep....any thoughts? I am not very proficent with the terminal, so if there is stuff I need to do on there, please make it as simple as possible, thanks in advance.

Comment: If anyone ever has a good answer to this USB mouse problem, I'd appreciate you letting me know at https://askubuntu.com/q/1358360/48214 which is my similar problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem with the touchpad on Lenovo Extreme and Carbon on Bionic (Ubuntu 18.04).  I was having to run `sudo rmmod psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse`.  I never figured out why, but the mouse driver gets hung after returning from suspend.  This underlying driver is the same as a regular mouse.

[Touchpad not working after suspending laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671910/touchpad-not-working-after-suspending-laptop)

Comment: +1. I appreciated your answer and was optimistic that it would help with https://askubuntu.com/q/1358360/48214 but it did not. I was wondering if you could please take a look and let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks so much!