# Ubuntu displays out of rotation on wake from sleep

Tags: nvidia, wakeup, display-rotation

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Problem: I have a triple monitor setup and on wake from sleep, the orientation goes crazy.

All displays are out of rotation. i.e they're back at horizontal, when their normal setup is 90 degrees oriented. Does anyone know how to fix? I have the latest driver from nvidia.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in terminal:

```
xrandr -o normal
```

Or depending on your setup and preferences, you can also try:

```
xrandr -o left
xrandr -o right
```

Once you find the correct one for your monitor setup, and if this issue keeps happening every time you wake your monitor from sleep, you may consider creating a script that runs every time the computer wakes up that does the correct command.

Here are some instructions on how to add a script that runs on wake up: [Script on Wakeup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92218/how-to-execute-a-command-after-resume-from-suspend)