# Connecton failed -> Activation of network connection failed

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, vpn, ethernet

After I changed the settings for wired connection using **nm-connection-edtior** to connect automatically to the Vpn after system startup or after the system is turned on from suspend mode Im not able to connect to the Wired Connection automatically and I get the following error:
**Connecton failed -> Activation of network connection failed**

Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try maybe

```
service network-manager start &
```

then if that works see here how to make it run after resuming from suspend.

[how to execute a command after resume from suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92218/how-to-execute-a-command-after-resume-from-suspend)

Comment: Thanks, @pierrely. This solution solved my issue.