# how to make a bunch of command to automatically run as root on wakeup from suspend?

Tags: bash, kernel, scripts, suspend, dkms

I have seen lot of answers on this nothing seemed to work on my system (probably I did mistake)

I have dkms module of wifi installed which does not reload itself when I resume from suspend. So i need to run these commonds in terminal as `root`

`modprobe -r "wifi driver"`

`modprobe -i "wifi driver"`

I am new to linux and all that script stuff so i need in detail.

What exactly I need is how to make script (which will run the above commands as `root`) and what changes I need to make in this (as I want to run script when i resume from suspend).

```
[Unit]
Description=Some description
Before=sleep.target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStop=-/path/to/your/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

https://askubuntu.com/a/1041358/856436

If anyone knows any other ways to automatically reload a dkms kernel module please add as answer.

My System: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with kernel 4.20.3-042003-generic

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/a/92235/295286

Comment: Read `man pm-action` - it explains the scripts that are run at Suspend/Resume/Sleep/Wake times.

Comment: @waltinator It says no manual entry for pm-action