# ubuntustudio-controls jack and suspend//resume

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-studio, jack, audio-jack

After my computer resume,
I have to `pkill jack` and start ubuntustudio controls and click on the button "start or restart jack".

I am on my way to create a resume script ([how to execute a command after resume from suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1041358/11027))

```
[Unit]
Description=Fix jack audio after resume from suspend
After=suspend.target

[Service]
User=trif
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=??????????????????????

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

But at ExecStart, I'm a bit stuck. what to write?

```
pkill jack && what ?
```

How to restart jack with the same parameters of ubuntustudio-controls?
How to view the jack parameters line that ubuntustudio-controls launch maybe? Or, is there a hidden parameter to ubuntustudio-controls to launch jack when it launch?

Answer (score 1):

Jack simply doesn't support suspend/resume as it's simply not designed for it. You need to stop Jack via ubuntustudio-controls before putting your machine into a suspend state.

Comment: ok ! maybe if ubuntustudio-controls support a parameter like ubuntustudio-controls --suspend and ubuntustudio-controls --resume , i could easily write the two services scripts that executes at sleep and resume

Comment: All ubuntustudio-controls does is act as a gui frontend to Jack, it doesn't run in the background. Additionally, it doesn't support command-line parameters. That's beyond the scope of the project.